# Unable to authenticate Azure Devops with Gitlab repo

Tags: azure, authentication, gitlab, devops, repo

How can one authenticate, as I am not been able to authenticate - even though I know credentials are correct.
Error which I am facing -
Clone URL is incorrect.
Clone URL requires authorization.